# unable to retrieve my data-name attribute

Tags: javascript

Hello I have a purchase order in which I want to retrieve a data-name to put the parent class in invisible, but it does not seem to work

Surely an error in my code or so I have to look for another way.

I give you my code in the hope of finding a solution to this problem.

But be careful I have more than 300 articles, my goal is to find a very precise data-name and to hide its parent div

```js
let nom = 2001
let pid = $("a").attr("data-name").parent(".panel");
console.log(pid)
if (pid === nom) {
  $("a").parent(".panel").css("display", "none");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 couleur1 testcard">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="">
      <h3 class="card-title centrer_titre_texte couleur2">2001</h3>
      <div class="card-body stylecardbody">
        <div class="row mt-12">
          <div class="popupgallery">
            <div class="position-relative product">
              <a class="example-image-link">
                <div class="overlay w-100 h-100 position-absolute justify-content-center">
                  <span class="align-self-center">clic pour agrandir</span></div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 " style="margin-top: 15px; ">
            <p class="card-text centrer_titre_texte">Perle de 2 mm</p>
            <div class="centrer_titre_texte">
              <p>3 perles identiques</p>
              <p>1,10 euros</p>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="articleBtndecription styledescription">Description</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <select class="form-select styleselect " id="2001" aria-label="2001" onchange="changeQte(this);">
              <option selected value="1">1 sachet </option>
              <option value="2">2 sachets</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <a data-name="2001" data-qte="1" data-checkbox="2001" class="btn btn-primary ajouter-panier b-items__item__add-to-cart">
                            ajouter au panier
                          </a>
          <div class="panel" style="display:block">
            <a data-qte2="0" data-name="2001" class="btn  ajouter-panier ">retirer panier
                            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `attr("data-name")` returns a string. Strings don't have a `.parent()` method. What is `.parent(".panel")` supposed to mean when you assign to `pid`?

Comment: `$("a").attr("data-name")` will return the `data-name` attribute of the first `<a>` tag. That's `<a class="example-image-link">` which doesn't have that attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are calling the `parent()` function on the result of `$("a").attr("data-name")`, which is a string containing the value of the `data-name` attribute of the first `a` element in the page. Since a string does not have a `parent()` function, this will cause an error.

Secondly, in the line `if (pid === nom)`, you are comparing the pid variable which is a `jQuery` object to the `nom` variable which is a number. This comparison will always return false, since a `jQuery` object and a number are not equal.

So to resolve your problem, you can modify the code to look like this:

```js
let nom = "2001";
let pid = $("a[data-name='" + nom + "']").parent(".panel");
console.log(pid);
if (pid.length > 0) {
  pid.css("display", "none");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 couleur1 testcard">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="">
      <h3 class="card-title centrer_titre_texte couleur2">2001</h3>
      <div class="card-body stylecardbody">
        <div class="row mt-12">
          <div class="popupgallery">
            <div class="position-relative product">
              <a class="example-image-link">
                <div class="overlay w-100 h-100 position-absolute justify-content-center">
                  <span class="align-self-center">clic pour agrandir</span></div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 " style="margin-top: 15px; ">
            <p class="card-text centrer_titre_texte">Perle de 2 mm</p>
            <div class="centrer_titre_texte">
              <p>3 perles identiques</p>
              <p>1,10 euros</p>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="articleBtndecription styledescription">Description</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <select class="form-select styleselect " id="2001" aria-label="2001" onchange="changeQte(this);">
              <option selected value="1">1 sachet </option>
              <option value="2">2 sachets</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <a data-name="2001" data-qte="1" data-checkbox="2001" class="btn btn-primary ajouter-panier b-items__item__add-to-cart">
                            ajouter au panier
                          </a>
          <div class="panel" style="display:block">
            <a data-qte2="0" data-name="2001" class="btn  ajouter-panier ">retirer panier
                            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```